# Is possible integrate TFS with VisualSVN?

Tags: java, tfs, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, svnbridge

In my work they are using a system in Java that works as a TFS. We also use a plugin in eclipse to handle the versions of the projects. My question is if I can use VisualSVN, instead of the plugin, for better management of versions. In short, is it possible to use properties of TFS in VisualSVN ?. If possible, what can be used ? Thanks.

Comment: `"a system in Java that works as a TFS"` - *What?*  It's really not clear what you're describing or asking here.  But as a general word of advice it's usually not a good idea to get really clever and hack together various source control tools into a single solution.  Source control is critical enough and simple enough that a team should just pick a reliable tool and use it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The question could be "Is it possible to use properties of TFS in VisualSVN ?. If possible, what can be used ?".
Thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

SVN is a version control system. TFS is project planning, version control, build, testing, release, and so on in one package. Basically, it's a superset of SVN.

You can use all of the non-source control while keeping your source code in another version control system, but it would be hacky and awkward and require a bunch of hoop-jumping that just isn't necessary. You can migrate source code from SVN to TFS very easily, with fairly minor disruption.

TFS has two options for source control: TFVC, which is similar to SVN, and Git, which is not.

For Java developers, there's a plugin for Eclipse called Team Explorer Everywhere that gives them an IDE-integrated TFS experience.